# How do websites like appcomments.com or androlib.com get data, particularly the reviews?

Tags: iphone, android, scrape

Do they just scrape or are there APIs?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api

Answer (score 1):

I think they just scrape, because I haven't seen or heard of any APIs. Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689711/itunes-app-store-api

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same things and found http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ (this is not the official api, as it seems they arent' any). It would be nice if there was an official API in the same way itunes has made theirs available