# Android market sans device

Tags: android, google-play

I don't have an Android device. Is there any way to see the Google Android Market - on the emulator, on the Web, in a specialized client (*a la* iTunes)?

Comment: Overlaps with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are third party websites available which have reversed the market protocols and scraped data from them. Most prominently, there is http://www.appbrain.com/. Note that AppBrain does do "shovelware" filtering, so not all applications are visible.

There is a third party API which has figured out how to interact with the market and can query data for you: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how exactly do they filter?

Comment: Using that Android Market API has a big problem: it looks like if you use it too much, you get blocked. That's what seems to have happened to me, at least.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a web interface: https://market.android.com/