# Any Android Market API from Google?

Tags: android, google-play

Not sure if its a possible duplicate. If so please merge to the appropriate.

I am looking for Google Market API that can pull the following information:

1. List of categories (in Apps, Books, Movies) in the Google Market
2. List of Top free apps/books/movies (by no. of downloads, ratings etc.) in a given category.
3. List of Top Paid apps/books/movies (by no. of downloads, ratings etc.) in a given category.

Is there an official Google Market API available?

I came across the below project but the feature set it provides doesn't support this functionality.
http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: HTML scraping is open to everyone :) Just sayin'.

Answer (score 5):

These may be a little bit helpful for you..

- [How to fetch Android Market data when there is no API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api)
- [How do I use the unofficial Android Market API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944441/how-do-i-use-the-unofficial-android-market-api)
- http://www.mobiletuxedo.com/open-source-api-for-the-android-market/

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, check out [https://42matters.com/api](https://42matters.com/api?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=22091040) for more info. Supports lookup, search and top rankings per country

Update: 42matters Google Charts API - [https://42matters.com/api/top-google-charts](https://42matters.com/api/top-google-charts?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=22091040) now collects daily snapshots of top lists for 45 countries. Enjoy!

Disclaimer: I am part of the 42matters team

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/217907) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I would like you to mention that this API is only for **paying** customers.

Comment: The question was for an API "... from Google".  This is clearly not from Google, but a paid service, so your answer of "Yes there is..." is not correct.