# Android Marketplace crawler?

Tags: android, google-play, google-crawlers

I am working on a project. I need help crawling the android marketplace and retrieving absolutely everything possible. I found many third party crawler api's which help with this. However there a constraint marketplace enforces, you can only get 200 results for any request. So I have breakdown my request into multiple requests and retrieve 200 items at a time. I search by publisher (there are not many publishers who have more than 200 apps published). The difficulty there is I need to get a list of all publishers. and I want the list to be up to date.

Here are some API's I looked at:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

http://code.google.com/p/android-marketplace-crawler/

If you have other suggestions, it would great.
Also, I am willing to pay for these services.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any Android Market API from Google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469200/any-android-market-api-from-google)