# What is AndroidId in android-market-api?

Tags: android, google-play

I am using [Android market API](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)

```
MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
        session.setAuthSubToken(token);
        session.getContext().setAndroidId( Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                            "android_id"));


        String query = "map";
        AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder().setQuery(query)
                .setStartIndex(0).setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                .setWithExtendedInfo(true).build();

        session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ResponseContext context,
                    AppsResponse response) {

                Debug.e("", "Total App: " + response.getAppList().size());

                for (int i = 0; i < response.getAppCount(); i++) {
                    Debug.e("", "" + response.getApp(i).getTitle());
                }

            }
        });

        session.flush();
```

My logcat

```
04-03 15:35:44.748: W/System.err(28330): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Response code = 400, msg = Bad Request
```

It's issue of `setAndroidId` because if I am using [`dead000beef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944441/how-do-i-use-the-unofficial-android-market-api) as Android is then it works and above Android id (my galaxy s3 android id) does not work.

Is it android id actually?

Comment: This way is not effective. It is not an official API and it's developers can change or update several time, therefore you will need change your code or approach several time. I created an app with this unofficial API, first time it worked well, then after 1 month crashed, and again became working, then crashed again. And this API can retrieve information not about all applications on the Market. I think that the developers have their own database and they update it when they want. I decided to do not use this API.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong android id , this way worked for me

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String udid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    session = new MarketSession();
    session.getContext().setAndroidId(udid);
    session.setAuthSubToken(token);
```

Don't forget to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```