# Enable App's market updates programmatically

Tags: java, android, google-play

I'd like to add a check box to the App preferences for allowing the user to select if he wants or not automatic updates from Google Play for this app.

Is that possible? Is there some kind of API or call for setting this property? Thanks

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate but this thread will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469200/any-android-market-api-from-google Also, accordingh to the answer, only this non official api allows to manipulate market data, and it's read only... Nevertheless, a common option is to host on web server the last version number, check it at app startup and offer an update if one is available (via a market link intent).

Comment: Notably, Dianne Hackborn just railed about this practice in a comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849889/new-version-app/9887642#9887642

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all handled transparently by the Google Play app, where there are options for users to choose whether to allow automatic updating. There is no API for your app to manage this.