# How to receive app store information of installing/installed apk?

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android application development. I have to develop a service to receive broadcast information to know installing apk "app store" related information. For example: when I am installing an apk name as abc.apk from Google Play after intallation, a service run which tell "Installed abc.apk is from Google play".Similarly, when I am install same apk from Amazon appstore, the service notify me "Installed abc.apk is from Amazon appstore".

Please solve my problem or give related hint so that I can begin my service.

Comment: _"Please solve my problem"_. If you want someone to do your work for you, hire someone to do it. StackOverflow is not the appropriate place for that.

Comment: Check this [Any Android Market API from Google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469200/any-android-market-api-from-google)