# Link android app downloads with an advertising campaign

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to link the downloads of my android app with an advertising campaign.

Let's say a website does some advertising for me. Because of that advertising, my app is downloaded. How can I link each "instance" of the app downloaded because of that compain?

Any suggestion would be welcome...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api