# Is there any possible way to obtain the list of android applications in market?

Tags: android, google-play

I am looking for solution of retrieving the whole list of application name from the market. Is there any way of doing this?

Edited: 
I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api) is very useful for this...