# In-app update notification

Tags: android, in-app

Today, when I started the game greedy spider, there was a dialog box telling me there was an update and a link to get it from the market. I'd like to know how can I do that?

How can you change the app (like adding a dialog box at the opening) without pushing an update to the market?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way of doing it.

I can imagine something like that:

- There is an unofficial Market API which you can use to fetch the details about your app and check the version [How to fetch Android Market data when there is no API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api)
- You can start your own web-service which would return you the current app version

After you've fetched the new app version from some external source, the rest is pretty easy - get the current installed version from app's `PackageInfo` and show the dialog if it's lower that the newest one.