# Is there an API to get statictics on Google Play developer console?

Tags: api, statistics, google-play

Is there an api which can take an application statistics from google play such as : active installs, Android versions, device, country, .... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308346/how-to-fetch-android-market-data-when-there-is-no-api

Answer (score 0):

THis may be a starting point for you :
http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

or this for PHP
https://github.com/splitfeed/android-market-api-php