# Android google play app, give access to statistics

Tags: android, statistics, google-play

is there any way to give access to the statistics of a specific app on my google play developer account to a 3rd person?

I have various apps, one of them is developed for a customer and he asks access to the downloads and rest statistics.

Answer (score 0):

At present, Google Play does not provide mechanism to enable access to a specific app alone, although you could give access to your whole Developer Console. The only thing you can restrict is the financial information. I hope this is not what you want.

In your case, you could provide screenshots if that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up to use a google api to retrieve the statistics and create my web front end to show them to my customer.

You can find at http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ a php version of the backend.

kudos to this post too: [Is there an API to get statictics on Google Play developer console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362412/is-there-an-api-to-get-statictics-on-google-play-developer-console)

Comment: I make clear that none of the linked code is mine. All credits go to the corresponding authors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I concerned, there is now way to give access to statistics only to 3-rd person, besides giving him your account information. For my personal usage, I developed a widget for tracking some statistics of my application and eventually I released it on the market. So I think it will be helpful to you as well [Applications Tracker Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realex.howismyapp) is the app which will help you